# meaning of the notations $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ and $\# (G/2G)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Does anybody know what the following means? It was never introduced in the lecture...

> What is the meaning of $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$? And the meaning of $\#(G/2G)$ where $G$ is a additive group?

Thanks for all efforts.

Comment: One meaning of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is the set of integer vectors of length $n.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression $\mathbb{Z}^n$ denotes the collection of $n$-tuples of integers, i.e.
$$\mathbb{Z}^n=\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}}_{n\text{ times}}=\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mid a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
It is a group under coordinate-wise addition; see [product group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups).

The expression $\#(G/2G)$ denotes the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) (i.e. size) of the [quotient group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) $G$ modulo the subgroup $2G$. The subgroup $2G$ is defined to be
$$2G=\{2g\mid g\in G\}$$
where $2g=g+g$.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: @Zev is $\mathbb{Z}^n$ a module using component-wise operations?

Comment: @J.D. Well, one must really specify module *over what ring*; but presumably you mean $\mathbb{Z}$-module. The answer is yes: in fact, any abelian group $G$ (such as $\mathbb{Z}^n$) can be given the structure of a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, by setting for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $g\in G$, $$n\cdot g:=ng=\begin{cases}\underbrace{g+\cdots+g}_{n\text{ times}}\text{ if }n\geq0\\\\\\\\\\ -\underbrace{(g+\cdots+g)}_{-n\text{ times}}\text{ if }n<0\end{cases}$$
See the second bullet point [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Examples).